# Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

Tags: content-security-policy

I have integrated the single-sign-on in our application using WsFedration(ADFS)
after the sign-out, it's redirecting to the page as successfully log out and back to the login page.
this follow is working correctly after hosting in the windows server, but after the hosting, to the Nginx server I'm having a problem, it's not redirecting to the login page, console error says,

> Refused to frame 'https://xxx-yyy.zzz.rr/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

then I search regarding this and added the Content Security Policy (CSP) to the Nginx config file like below.

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "style-src-elem 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' none";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'unsafe-inline'  'self'; https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css  ";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' 'unsafe-inline' none";

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com  https://fonts.gstatic.com";
```

I tried several ways, but I couldn't figure it out , if anyone can help me to fix this issue much appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1. You publish a several CSPs at the same time, they work not as you think.  If multiple CSP published, they are combined with logical 'AND'.
   But you trickely use **unique directives** in each CSP, therefore the whole set would work as intended if not the `default-src` directive. If it's issued in a separate CSP, the `default-src` overrides all other fallback-directives. As result you have `'unsafe-inline'  'self'` rule for all directives.

You have to place all directives in the one `add_header Content-Security-Policy`.

2. You have some [errors](https://csplite.com/csp/check/?pl=eJzNj8FKAzEQhu9C32HJJadNSosKydG7CD5Bmp1sA9mZZWcqFvHdm21lBS161EuYzP%2Fx801wW%2FfG9VEpvyr%2F6NndOlXgBYry2W38OXt4flJ1utvcO8VyLNDyFFsoMDT6gBwStBlLRtCNZihJN3uRkZ21CNJhMDsiYZnCGDs0kQa7LOzWrM3aRubPXduX47jPkZBNDZqlLREKm56oLxDGzOeqSmi%2Fulm8%2FodSNUpTGH400kj1V8kOUjgUucp%2BwP6v%2FANGYKGJF%2BsvgvMRM12LLgdcx37R%2F2bEEiTHOfLKv58Amp%2Fudw%3D%3D#result) in rules, for example:

- `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css` source should have trailing `/`, because it;s a folder name, not file name.
- `none` token should be single quoted - `'none'`, and it will be ignored if it's combined with the other sources.
- `"frame-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' none"` - the `frame-src` is not support `'unsafe-inline'` token.
- `"frame-ancestors 'self' 'unsafe-inline' none"` - the `frame-ancestors` is not support `'unsafe-inline'` token.
- `"font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com  https://fonts.gstatic.com"` - the `font-src` is not support `'unsafe-inline'` token.
- `"default-src 'unsafe-inline'  'self'; https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css  "` - the `;`(semicolon) after `'self'` does finish the `default-src` rules set, therefore `https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css` is counted as directive name.

Here your rules:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy " \
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css https://fonts.googleapis.com/css/; \
font-src 'self' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; \
frame-ancestors 'self'; \
frame-src 'self'; \
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css https://fonts.googleapis.com/css/; \
style-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css https://fonts.googleapis.com/css/; \
"
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, if I add as you mentioned, I cannot restart the Nginx, it says end up with an error

Comment: Remove backslashes and pull everything into one line. Although nginx should understand [backslashes as line breaks](https://serverfault.com/questions/780075/how-to-split-the-nginx-config-across-multiple-lines).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I follow the tip of @granty about first topic

> You publish a several CSPs at the same time, they work not as you think. If multiple CSP published, they are combined with logical 'AND'.

And I "remove" the Header in my Nginx configuration:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "";
```

In my Keycloak the Headers of Security Defenses are:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
```